# How can I make the scroll of dynamic iframe disappear when it comes from the other website?

Tags: html, css, iframe

I'm trying to make the scroll disappear to the iframe. The iframe came from another website domain. and the iframe is dynamic so every time it has a different content/output.

**Addition:**so the iframe is dynamic /product{any number could be here} that's why it's hard to add a fixed height.

also the height of for example URL/product1 = 2000px, URL/product2 = 2300px.

I did try this code:

```html
<div style="overflow:hidden;>
 <iframe src="https://www.example.com/product1"></iframe>
</div>
```

or

```html
<iframe src="https://www.example.com/product1" style="overflow:hidden;"></iframe>
```

both doesn't work.

Also, I did try to use **scrolling="no"** attribute but that doesn't load the whole content.

I tried getting the height of iframe but it's throwing me a cross-origin frame error since its different domain.

Maybe anyone experienced this already? Thank you.

Comment: If you can not get the actual height of the content, then this would just hide any overflow that might occur in the iframe at the height you have given it, making parts of it inaccessible … doesn’t sound like that would make much sense to begin with?

Comment: I couldn't get the height of the actual iframe because it's from a different domain it's against same-origin policy. also the content from iframe is ranging 2000px-2300px height that's why it automatically have the scroll and i did give it a try doing scrolling="no" to iframe and add fix height of 2300px so all of the content i will be able to see it but for the iframe that has 2000px height it looks weird and have alot of extra white spaces.

Comment: Yes, I am aware that you can not get the height in such a situation (unless the other side is willing to help you along with that.) _“add fix height of 2300px so all of the content i will be able to see it but for the iframe that has 2000px height it looks weird and have alot of extra white spaces”_ - well, yeah, naturally. But there are little other options - either you provide a high enough iframe height to begin with, then disable scrolling, and live with some extra white space - or you work with a lower height, and accept that scrolling will then be necessary in some of the cases.

Comment: I see yes i guess i'll just have to accept that extra white space lol. thank you so much by the way sir! have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

Work Properly. Its work for me.

```html
<iframe src="<<URL>>" height="500" width="600"  scrolling="no" style="overflow: hidden"></iframe>
```